# Why the other two object properties doesn't show up when I console log the object?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Submit (props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({email: '', username: '', password: ''});

    function handleChange(event) {
        setData({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }   

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(data);

        let sentData = encodeURIComponent(data);
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/', sentData)
        .then(response =>  {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit} method = "post">
                <input name = "email" placeholder = "enter your email" type = "text" value = {data.email} onChange = {handleChange}>

                </input>
                <input name = "username" placeholder = "enter your username" type = "text" value = {data.username} onChange = {handleChange}>

                </input>
                <input name = "password" placeholder = "enter your password" type = "password" value = {data.password} onChange = {handleChange}>

                </input>
                <div>
                <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm pretty newbie in react. When I type the inputs and click submit, the `console.log(data)` on `handleSubmit` only prints the object with last typed property. For example suppose I type password then username then email, it prints {email: 'blabla'} and ignoring password, username? How can modify the code to print the whole object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are returning the last updated property only.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-maxwell-odkz0?file=/src/Submit.js)

Let say when you edit the `username` property then you are returning the object with only the `username` property. It should return all properties that already exist and update the `username` only.

```
setData((state) => ({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
```